# How to use Yammer API using AAD authentication method

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal, yammer, yammer-api

I'm trying to use AAD authentication for my Yammer connection but I'm getting this error so any help or suggestion would be really apprecaited.

```
| No user id found for O365 JWT
```

```
$ClientId = ""
$SecretID = "" 
$tenantid = ""
$GroupID  = '12856115'
$Params = @{
    "URI"     = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$TenantID/oauth2/token"
    "Body"    = "client_id=$ClientID&client_secret=$SecretID&resource=https://graph.microsoft.com&grant_type=client_credentials"
    "Method"  = 'POST'
    "Headers" = @{
        "Content-Type" = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
}

$Result = Invoke-RestMethod @Params

$GroupCycle = 1
$Params1 = @{
    "URI"            = "https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/users/in_group/$GroupId.xml?page=$GroupCycle"
    "Method"         = 'GET'
    "Authentication" = 'OAuth'
    "Token"          = (ConvertTo-SecureString -String $Result.access_token -AsPlainText -Force)
}
$Members = Invoke-RestMethod @Params1
$Members.Value
```

Comment: See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/yammer/authentication-1?force_isolation=true  There is more than one type of authentication and server has to be set to same mode that client is using.

Comment: @jdweng that's the doc that I'm following right now. I'm trying to use AAD token method but I'm stuck here that's why. any help?

Comment: Your jwt token is not valid or the id doesn't match the token.  See : https://www.miniorange.com/yammer-jwt-single-signon(sso)-solution

Answer (score 0):

> Note that, you are using `client_credentials` flow that won't work
> with **Delegated** permissions. In addition to that, you are passing
> **wrong** resource to get Yammer token that's giving you the error.

I registered one Azure AD application and granted **API permissions** to it like below:

[image]

Now, I generated access token using **client credentials** flow via Postman by passing same **resource** as you like below:

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/token
grant_type:client_credentials
client_id:<appID>
client_secret:<secret>
resource: https://graph.microsoft.com
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I used above token to call Yammer API, I got **same error** as you like below:

```
GET https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/users.json
```

**Response:**

[image]

> To resolve the error, you need to use **Delegated** flows like
> authorization code flow, username password flow etc... with
> **resource** as `https://api.yammer.com` to generate access token.

In my case, I used **username password** flow and generated access token like below:

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/token
grant_type:password
client_id:<appID>
client_secret:<secret>
resource: https://api.yammer.com
username: username@domain.onmicrosoft.com
password: **********
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I used this token to call Yammer API, I got **response** successfully like below:

```
GET https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/users.json
```

**Response:**

[image]

In your case, modify your powershell script by changing **resource** and **grant_type** like below:

```
$ClientId = "appID"
$SecretID = "Secret" 
$tenantid = "tenantID"

$Params = @{
    "URI"     = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$TenantID/oauth2/token"
    "Body"    = "client_id=$ClientID&client_secret=$SecretID&resource=https://api.yammer.com&grant_type=password&username=username@domain.onmicrosoft.com&password=********"
    "Method"  = 'POST'
    "Headers" = @{
        "Content-Type" = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
}

$Result = Invoke-RestMethod @Params

$Params1 = @{
    "URI"     = "https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/users.json"
    "Method"  = 'GET'
    "Headers" = @{
        "Authorization" = "Bearer $($Result.access_token)"
    }
}

$Members = Invoke-RestMethod @Params1

$Members
```

**Response:**

[image]